# How to extend the timeout of a SQL query

Tags: c#, .net, sql, timeout

This is not a connection timeout as a connection to the database is made fine.  The problem is that the stored procedure that I'm calling takes longer than, say, 30 seconds and causes a timeout.

The code of the function looks something like this:

```
SqlDatabase db = new SqlDatabase(connectionManager.SqlConnection.ConnectionString);
return db.ExecuteScalar(Enum.GetName(typeof(StoredProcs), storedProc), parameterValues);
```

The ExecuteScalar call is timing out.  How can I extend the timeout period of this function?

For quick stored procedures, it works fine.  But, one of the functions takes a while and the call fails.  I can't seem to find any way to extend the timeout period when the ExecuteScalar function is called this way.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you are using the EnterpriseLibrary (and it looks like you are) try this:

```
 Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database db = Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("ConnectionString");
 System.Data.Common.DbCommand cmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand("StoredProcedureName");
 cmd.CommandTimeout = 600;
 db.AddInParameter(cmd, "ParameterName", DbType.String, "Value");

 // Added to handle paramValues array conversion
 foreach (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter param in parameterValues) 
 {
     db.AddInParameter(cmd, param.ParameterName, param.SqlDbType, param.Value);
 }

 return cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Edited to handle the paramValues array directly based on the comments. I also included your ConnectionString value:

```
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database db = Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(connectionManager.SqlConnection.ConnectionString);
System.Data.Common.DbCommand cmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand("StoredProcedureName", parameterValues);
cmd.CommandTimeout = 600;
return cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: Hmmm... I don't have access to the ParameterNames.  The parameterValues variable in my sample code is defined as "object[] parameterValues".  Can I still add the parameters without knowing the names only the order?

Comment: I added code that should convert your paramValues array into the parameters expected by the DbCommand.

Comment: No need.  You just add it to the GetStoredProcCommand command.

Answer (score 27):

You do this by setting the [`SqlCommand.CommandTimeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout(VS.71).aspx) property.

Comment: Which would work great if I was using a SqlCommand... but, I'm not.

Comment: Yes, you are. SqlDatabase isn't part of the standard data provider; it's a wrapper class that someone has written, and it will use an SqlCommand object internally.

Comment: The "someone" may be Microsoft, though -- is this the SQLDatabase class from Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary?

Comment: @Joel, that function is defined in a file called Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.dll Hmmm... not sure if I have the source code for that. Searching...

Comment: Rewrite it to use db.CreateConnection(); the you'll have 4-5 extra lines of code, but easy access to the SqlCommand object.

Answer (score 6):

I think this might be a better way to do this (as of Enterprise Library 6.0):

```
SqlDatabase db = new SqlDatabase(connectionManager.SqlConnection.ConnectionString);
System.Data.Common.DbCommand cmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand(storedProc, parameterValues);
cmd.CommandTimeout = 600;
return db.ExecuteScalar(cmd);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to add anything new to the existing answers. It just repeats the existing solution, which is `cmd.CommandTimeout(nnn)`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this one

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder connectionStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connection.ConnectionString);
connectionStringBuilder.ConnectTimeout = 180;
connection.ConnectionString = connectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString;

connection.Open();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp_ProcedureName", connection);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.CommandTimeout = connection.ConnectionTimeout;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

Answer (score -2):

Mladen is right but if you have to do this you probably have a bigger problem with the proc itself. Under load it might take much longer than your new timeout. Might be worth spending some quality time with the proc to optimize.

Comment: Thanks for telling me to go optimize my application. Sigh. In the long run that may happen, but for TODAY I just need to get this thing running.

Comment: I certainly meant no offense. It's just that if SQL is timing out, it is unlikely you'll be able to find a timeout # that will work in every situation. You WANT SQL to time out in many cases and the default is still pretty long.